# How to launch a Virtual Machine in EC2 using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

I am totally new to AWS. I have been given a official task to explore the AWS api for java So that we can launch a Virtual Machine ON EC2. I have gone through the official docs at [sdk-for-java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java) but having few doubts:

1. Would I need to deploy the java code on EC2 ?
2. Can Java code create and launch the Virtual Server or we can only start it through code and need to create the virtual machine through EC2 dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, since you're very unfamiliar with AWS, have a read through their documentation. I know there's a lot there but the following links should directly apply to your situation:

[Concepts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html)
[Getting started with AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/java/)
[Java examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-ec2.html)

To answer your question, you want to start a virtual machine. Within AWS, these are referred to as "instances". To launch an instance using the API, you could execute the code that makes the API call locally and as long as you have valid credentials etc, the code should work. Your code does not need to be run inside of EC2.

The following code will run an EC2 instance for you as long as you have valid credentials and the AWS-SDK included in your java project.

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest =
   new RunInstancesRequest();

runInstancesRequest.withImageId("ami-4b814f22") // This is a base image, for example a ubuntu or linux instance
                   .withInstanceType("m1.small") // The size of the instance, these cost more the more powerful they are
                   .withMinCount(1) // Minimum amount of instances you want to launch
                   .withMaxCount(1); // Maximum amount of instances you want to launch
```

Comment: As per my understanding the above code will run the already created instance.How we can create the instance ? are ImageId and InstanceType having fixed value ?

Comment: The API call is named RunInstancesRequest but this will spawn a new instance. I agree it's poor and inconsistent wording on AWS's part.

To create a server you will need a root volume, containing an OS and the sort of basics, this is where AMI's come in. AWS has loads of defaults. For example a Ubuntu 16.04, an Amazon Linux, a Red hat instance, take your pick (Google for the actual Id's). There are also public AMI's created by the community but I suggest you stick to the amazon ones. When you go through the launch instance process in the actual console, this will become clear.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: I execute the above code but can't see any running instance in EC2 console.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation I've sent, you will need to include credentials for your Java AWS Client to sent authenticated requests to AWS. When you've done this, look at the response for your api call, what is going wrong?

Comment: I am following the same link and page "How to run a Amazon EC2 instance". I am using eclipse aws plugin so AWS account is already setup there. It's throwing an exception "Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty".

Comment: If I'm seeing this right, it's looking for a Security Group id/name. Either you leave this parameter out of your RunInstances invocation and let it select the default SG or you choose one that is currently existing in your AWS environment.